# Need to remove files that are placed to remote server using mput

Tags: shell, scripting

Current logic is deleting all files from local directory,
where in files that are placed in remote directory should get deleted and any new files in local directory should be available for next run

```
function XXXX() {
sftp -o XXXXXXX  << EOF
  mput *
  quit
EOF
TS=`date +%y%m%d%H%M%s`
echo "Time after sending is $TS"

RC=$?
if [ $RC -eq 0 ]
  then
    rm $DIR/*  #instead of deleting all files want to delete only files that are placed to remote server.
  else echo "sftp failed.  RC is $RC"
fi }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [`lftp`](https://manned.org/lftp/7527fb00) is a viable alternative here:

```
lftp -e mput -E * -u user,password sftp://domain.com
```

- `-c` execute command(s), then exit
- `mput -E *` upload all files matching wildcard, then delete source
- `-u user,password` login credentials

Comment: Thanks Felix. My concern is that more files are added to local directory during mput that are not added to remote location (but should be added) and when removing all are removed from local directory. Is there a way to check what files are copied in sFTP and then delete only those.

Comment: How to use an array to store file names at mput and rm those files looping through array?

Comment: @Lakshmi You could just use `ls` with sftp, then only delete files that were listed on the remote server (e.g. `sftp << EOF \ ls \ quit \ EOF > reflist ; for file in $DIR/* ; do if [[ $(grep $file reflist ) ]] ; then rm $file ; else echo $file was not transferred ; fi ; done` .... adjust so that the `ls`-output and the actual file path match (e.g. `basename` or alike - depends on how the output looks like). Problem: files with identical names that are newer on the sending side, but older files were not overwritten. For those cases you would also need e.g. checking of modification dates.

Comment: @Lakshmi Also regarding your concern: the `lftp` command would only delete files it transferred, so new files would neither be transferred nor deleted. I.e. the wildcard expansion would be happening during command initialization.

Comment: Thanks Felix. I will try these options and will post my results.

Comment: @Felix.is this syntax correct. will the ls writes files to reflist?                                          
   sFTP << EOF
  mput *
  ls > reflist
  quit
EOF